# SELinux: cannot confine Firefox process to mozilla_t domain

Tags: fedora, selinux, firefox, mozilla

My goal is to execute Firefox in the `mozilla_t` domain instead of `unconfined_t`.  The machine runs Fedora 20 with SELinux in enforcing mode.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this right.  No matter what I do, the process is always executed in the `unconfined_t` domain.

I know that there are three conditions to be met:

1. the target file context (`mozilla_exec_t`) must be executable for the source domain (`unconfined_t` or `bin_t`)
2. the target file context (`mozilla_exec_t`) must be marked as an entry point for the target domain (`mozilla_t`)
3. the source domain (`unconfined_t` or `bin_t`) must be allowed to transition to the target domain (`mozilla_t`)

The target file is the firefox script at `/usr/bin/firefox` which calls `/usr/lib64/firefox/run-mozilla.run`, which again runs the binary `/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox`.  This is the output of `ls -Z` on these files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/bin/firefox
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/lib64/firefox/run-mozilla.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:mozilla_exec_t:s0 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

The **first** condition is met, as `unconfined_t` is allowed to execute the target file context `mozilla_exec_t`.

```
$ sesearch -s unconfined_t -t mozilla_exec_t -c file -p execute -Ad
Found 1 semantic av rules:
   allow unconfined_t mozilla_exec_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock execute execute_no_trans entrypoint open } ;
```

The **second** condition is met, as `mozilla_exec_t` is defined as the entry point to the `mozilla_t` domain.

```
$ sesearch -s mozilla_t -t mozilla_exec_t -c file -p entrypoint -Ad
Found 1 semantic av rules:
   allow mozilla_t mozilla_exec_t : file { ioctl read getattr lock execute execute_no_trans entrypoint open } ;
```

Per default configuration in Fedora 20, the **third** condition is **not** met because `unconfined_t` cannot transition to `mozilla_t`.

```
$ sesearch -s unconfined_t -t mozilla_t -c process -p transition -Ad
(no output)
```

To fix this I have written a short policy module that grants `unconfined_t` process permission to transition to `mozilla_t`.

```
module rekado 1.0;

require {
  type unconfined_t;
  type mozilla_t;
  class process transition;
}

allow unconfined_t mozilla_t : process transition ;
```

Now I should be able to run the Firefox process in domain `mozilla_t` by directly running the executable `/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox`, but the process remains in domain `unconfined_t`.

What is going on here?  Why isn't the process context `mozilla_t`?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: @Huygens Unfortunately, I did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly had it. The problem is that the allow rule

> allow unconfined_t mozilla_t : process transition ;

*allows* the transition to take place, but doesn't *cause* it to happen. For that you need a type_transition rule:

> type_transition unconfined_t mozilla_exec_t : process mozilla_t;

This causes the transition to occur when an unconfined_t process executes a mozilla_exec_t file.

With that done, firefox won't run. I used audit2allow to track down the additional rules needed to allow firefox to manage temp files and sockets.

Here is a policy that works on my CentOS 6-based VM. It needs the selinux boolean mozilla_read_content enabled (via: `setsebool -P mozilla_read_content 1`).

```
module mozilla 1.0;

require {
  role unconfined_r;
  type unconfined_t;
  type mozilla_t;
  type mozilla_exec_t;
  type tmp_t;
  type user_tmp_t;
  type fs_t;
  class process transition;
  class file { ioctl getattr setattr create read write unlink open relabelto };
  class dir { ioctl getattr setattr create read write unlink add_name remove_name };
  class filesystem getattr;
  class sock_file { getattr setattr create read write unlink };
  class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

role unconfined_r types mozilla_t;

allow unconfined_t self:file relabelto;
allow unconfined_t mozilla_t : process transition ; 

type_transition unconfined_t mozilla_exec_t : process mozilla_t;

allow mozilla_t fs_t:filesystem getattr;
allow mozilla_t tmp_t:file { ioctl getattr setattr create write unlink open };
allow mozilla_t tmp_t:dir  { ioctl getattr setattr create read write add_name remove_name };
allow mozilla_t user_tmp_t:dir { ioctl create write add_name setattr remove_name };
allow mozilla_t user_tmp_t:sock_file { getattr setattr create read write unlink };
allow mozilla_t unconfined_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

To compile and install it:

> # checkmodule -M -m -o mozilla.mod mozilla.te
>   checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from rekado.te
>   checkmodule:  policy configuration loaded
>   checkmodule:  writing binary representation (version 10) to mozilla.mod
>   # semodule_package -o mozilla.pp -m mozilla.mod
>   # sudo semodule -i mozilla.pp